# Linking SFML-2.2 On 64bit Win7 Using g++

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, sfml

I have compiled my program using the command below which ran without errors.

```
g++ -c main.cpp -I C:\SFML-2.2\include -std=c++11
```

Then, I tried to link it using command:

```
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L C:\SFML-2.2\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

These are the errors that return from the above command:

```
d:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\SFML-2.2\lib/libsfml-graphics.a when
searching for -lsfml-graphics
d:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\SFML-2.2\lib\libsfml-graphics.a when
searching for -lsfml-graphics
d:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\SFML-2.2\lib/libsfml-graphics.a when
searching for -lsfml-graphics
d:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-graphics
```

The errors continue exactly the same but instead with "skipping incompatible C:\SFML-2.2\lib\sfml-graphics.lib when searching for -lsfml-graphics", and the same with -lsfml-system.

The project folder is located at: *C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\SFMLTEST* and SFML folder at: *D:\SFML-2.2*


I have now downloaded the SFML-2.2 for 32bit windows as recommended on their site and GCC 4.9.2 MinGW (DW2) - 32-bit, and I have g++ version: (GCC) 4.9.1

> On Windows, choosing 32 or 64-bit libraries should be based on which
>   platform you want to compile for, not which OS you have. Indeed, you
>   can perfectly compile and run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit Windows.

Now my question is, what do the above errors mean? And how can I fix them?

**EDIT:**
Found solution some months ago, adding answer here as it might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was:

g++ wanted *64 bit* libraries while I gave it *32 bit* libraries despite the recommendations from the website. 
The solution was to download and build the 64 bit libraries.